# One To Many relationships for Innerjoins?

Tags: mysql

Does a database relationship need to be established before you can impliment a INNERJOIN In a PHP Query?

Furthermore, when I export my Database via PMA; My already created relationships to not get exported. So I'm having to re-create my relationships apun every import.

Is it possible to export with the relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The relationship is preferred when being optimized, but a relationship is not required to use a `JOIN`.

When exporting your database, make sure you use the **Custom - display all possible options** method. You may missing an option that is not including those constraints. Another possible reason is if you're not using **InnoDb** as the table engine, otherwise those constraints are discarded with **MyISAM**. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296730/disappearing-foreign-keys-in-phpmyadmin) for more info.

Comment: and an answer to my second part?